# Dictionary inside of another dictionary doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have created:

```
Public 123 As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))))
```

Now I need go through the loop to complete this dictionary from an Excel file. But I have an error in else of 3 if:
"The specified number of parameters does not match the expected number"

```
Dim search As Boolean = False
    Dim counter As Integer = 2
    Dim holder1 As String = "qwerty"
    Dim holder2 As String = "qwerty"
    Dim holder3 As String = "qwerty"
    Dim holder4 As String = "qwerty"
    While search = False
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sheet.Cells(counter, 1).Value) Then
            search = True
        End If

        If Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text = holder1 Then
            If Sheet.Cells(counter, 5).Text = holder2 Then
                If Sheet.Cells(counter, 7).Text = holder3 Then
                    If Sheet.Cells(counter, 10).Text = holder4 Then 
                        123(Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text(Sheet.Cells(counter, 5).Text(Sheet.Cells(counter, 7).Text(Sheet.Cells(counter, 10))))).Add(Sheet.Cells(counter, 10).Text, Sheet.Cells(counter, 8).Text)
                    Else
                        123(Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text(Sheet.Cells(counter, 5).Text(Sheet.Cells(counter, 7).Text))).Add(Sheet.Cells(counter, 10).Text, Sheet.Cells(counter, 8).Text) 
                        holder4 = Sheet.Cells(counter, 10).Text
                    End If
                Else
                    123(Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text(Sheet.Cells(counter, 5).Text)).Add(Sheet.Cells(counter, 7).Text, New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))) ERROR
                    holder3 = Sheet.Cells(counter, 7).Text
                End If
            Else
                123(Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text).Add(Sheet.Cells(counter, 5).Text, New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer)))
                holder2 = Sheet.Cells(counter, 5).Text
            End If
        Else
            123.Add(Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text, New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer)))) 
            holder1 = Sheet.Cells(counter, 2).Text
        End If
        counter += 1

    End While
```

Comment: That can't even compile ; an identifier can't start by a digit so `123` as a name can't be valid. For the rest that's so much nesting to be readable or maintenable. You really should make some meaningful classes to hold those intermediate "steps"

Comment: You need to explain your goal because what you are doing makes no sense at all.